# How would assign an integer the value of a char for a char value?

Tags: java, arrays, encryption

I'm currently working on a project which requires me to make a simple encrypter and decrypter. I was thinking about assigning char's a value from 1-26 that is randomly done. However, I'm confused about integers with chars. I want to be able say the 1 = a and then if the user inputs a, the encrypted version would be 1.

Comment: `int letter; if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') { letter = ch - 'a' + 1; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Characters are unicode points, you find the diference between your character and 'a'

```
int val = ch -'a' + 1;
```

[This guy will help you out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15027342/7108229)

Comment: Thanks! Also, is there a method similar to map.put that works like map.put(9,'a'); I intend to 'decrypt' it so, I would require to input 1 and the character 'a' is returned.