# Converting Letters from String to Numbers

Tags: java

Hello I am new to java and I am having a hard time on converting the letters from strings to numbers for example, the user will input "I am Okay" and the output will become 901-13015-11-1-25 since,
I = 9 space = 0 A = 1 M = 13 space = 0 O = 15 K = 11 A = 1 Y = 25. I tried using switch, but I am having a hard time, because the program will print what I input in the string, well here is the test code I created, I hope someone can help me or give me tips and advices.

```
import java.util.*;
public class New2
{
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Input the First string: ");
    String fs = input.nextLine();
    
    fstoInt(fs);
    System.out.println(fs);

}

public static int fstoInt(String fs) {
    int num = 0;
    switch (fs) {
    case "A":
        num = 1;
        break;
    case "B":
        num = 2;
        break;
    case "C":
        num = 3;
        break;
    case "D":
        num = 4;
        break;
    case "E":
        num = 5;
        break;
    case "F":
        num = 6;
        break;
    case "G":
        num = 7;
        break;
    }
    return num;
}
}
```

Comment: You need to iterate the string one character at a time.

Comment: Probably [best to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147454/why-is-using-a-wild-card-with-a-java-import-statement-bad) the wild card import `import java.util.*;`

Comment: you can use `fs.charAt(i)-64` inside a for loop

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java - how to convert letters in a string to a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15027231/java-how-to-convert-letters-in-a-string-to-a-number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> output will become 901-13015-11-1-25 since, I = 9 space = 0 A = 1 M = 13 space = 0 O = 15 K = 11 A = 1 Y = 25

I don't think you read the assignment properly.

That would mean that: `AA` becomes `11`. And `K`... also becomes `11`. Not sure this is what you wanted.

```
switch (fs) {
    case "A":
```

assuming it's all consecutive, with "A" becoming 1, and "Z" becoming 26: characters are just numbers (their unicode value), and those letters are in sequence. So, instead of a gigantic switch block, all you need is:

```
int num = fs.charAt(0) - 'A' + 1;
```

this will turn "A" into 1, and "Z" into 26.

As the comments already said, your problem is that `fs` isn't just `"A"`. It's `"Hello"`. You need to loop through the characters. As space gets special treatment (turning into 0), and presumably anything that isn't "A" - "Z" should crash:

```
for (char c : fs.toCharArray()) {
    int num = charToCode(c);
}
```

and then write charToCode:

```
public int charToCode(char c) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    if (c == ' ') return 0;
    if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') return c - 'A' + 1;
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(
      "Only spaces and capital letters allowed");
}
```

Comment: uhm I mean in my assignment all characters from A have the formula A = 0+1, B = 1+1, C = 2+1 and so on...

Comment: Anyways thank you for the advice I learned something new from your comment and given code.

Comment: @Marcel yes, and with that formula, A is 1, and K is 11, and if you just pile numbers one after the other with nothing in between, `AA` becomes `11` and `K` also becomes `11`.

Comment: Thank you, but now I am having trouble on reversing the strings because the output needs to be reverse, I tried using arrays but I cannot seem to get it working.